# Formatting number within text

Tags: worksheet-function

I have the following formula 
=concatenate("Price is ", A1," of new price")
where the value "A1" is the percentage value.
What should I write in the formula so the percentage value of A1 appears as percent in the final text?

Now it appears as "Price is 0.35 of new price"

I would like to see "Price is 35% of new price"

Answer (score 2):

Use the formula:

```
=CONCATENATE("Price is ", TEXT(B1,"0%")," of new price")
```

For more details (including additional formatting options), see: [TEXT function - Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c).